# Cancel an uploading file. GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

I use [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) lib for uploading files on a server. There is a feature: cancel of file uploading. But how should I handle the action on the Java server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code related gwtupload shows different server side handling examples for this scenario.

Did you try cancel callback supported in the framework? You can find the examples here -http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/search?q=cancel&origq=cancel&btnG=Search+Trunk